# What if android crash before saving the purchaseToken?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I'm doing my first project using in-app billing on Android but there one thing I don't get:

We need to keep the purchaseToken whenever the purchase was succesfull in order to consume it later on. But there is no way to recover it if we don't save it on the first time we receive it. So if for instance Android crashed or something happens before we have time to consume/to save this token, how should we do then ? We won't ever be able to consume the purchase anymore without this token (which would be terribly anoying)...

To recall, the purchase data is stored in a String in JSON format :

```
'{
   "orderId":"GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567",
   "packageName":"com.example.app",
   "productId":"exampleSku",
   "purchaseTime":1345678900000,
   "purchaseState":0,
   "developerPayload":"bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ",
   "purchaseToken":"opaque-token-up-to-1000-characters"
 }'
```

Do you have any solution or explanation about something I would have misunderstood in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to getPurchases() api in the following link:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchases 
As long as you have yet to consume a purchase, you can get the unconsume purchase from getPurchases() api call. Just call getToken() to retrieve purchaseToken.